# Unit testing a method that returns a type MultipartFormDataContent and checking its content

Tags: c#, testing

I have a mapper method that returns a MultipartFormDataContent type being used as the content in a HttpRequestMessage request (its an API call to an external provider)

I want to be able to unit test the data that comes back and assert the fields created are correct

Example request -

```
using var fromContent = new StringContent(_options.Value.EmailFromAddress!);
using var toContent = new StringContent(emailAddress);

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { fromContent, "from" },
            { toContent, "to" }            
        };
```

What I can't work out how to do is something like this:

```
Assert content["from"] == "string"
```